# Output name/description of items in custom taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress

Having registered a custom taxonomy, how do I output the name/description of all items in that custom taxonomy to a page?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet to get your desired results.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
'orderby'    => 'count',
'hide_empty' => 0,
 ) );
foreach($terms as $term){
 echo $term->name;
 echo $term->description;
}
?>
```

You will replace **category** with your own taxonomy name and you can use your data as you want, for further reading [visit codes page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/#source-code)
Hope that makes sense by now